# Cannot read json file after uploading "go" package into AWS Lambda

Tags: go, lambda

I have go lang code to read some json file. It's running fine in local but I created Lambda package and uploaded the package in Lambda. It cannot read the file

```
import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
)

type MyEvent struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

func HandleRequest(ctx context.Context, name MyEvent) (string, error) {
    jsonBytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile("mappings.json")
    fmt.Println(string(jsonBytes))
    fmt.Println(err)
    return fmt.Sprintf("Hello %s!", name.Name), nil
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(HandleRequest)
}
```

How to read the file from AWS Lambda? Any idea on this?

Answer (score 1):

I have used your sample code and put in the zip file and also the mappings file that I used to test on AWS lambda. Link to code - https://github.com/nihanthd/stackoverflow/tree/master/lambda

Handler name in AWS lambda is ***trial***

Test Data to trigger the function using AWS lambda event

```
{
    "name": "Vignesh"
}
```

Commands used to build the executable and create the zip file

```
$ GOARCH=amd64 GOOS=linux go build trial.go
$ zip trial.zip trial mappings.json
```

Comment: There are some alternate ways to do it. We are using SAM Template. it does automatically for us.